# Synology Hyper Backup: "Access to destination denied" after deleting user

Tags: backup

I recently deleted a user who had previously created a local Hyper Backup task. This cased a problem with the backup tasks where the Owner has become "Not available" and the backup fails with the error "Access to destination denied". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the File Station app to browse and find the .hbk file. Right click on this file and go to Properties. Change the owner to a new owner who has access to the shared folder that the backup is saved to.

Answer (score 1):

Enable SSH and make connection through PuTTY. Use following command:

```
sudo chown -R --from=oldUser newUser /volume1/backup/Syno/file.hbk
```

Answer (score -1):

Open SSH console and change the access rights of the backup destination:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /volumeUSB1/usbshare/yourDestination.hbk/
```

This will give read/write access to all users, regardless of the owner or group.

Background: If you create a backup task in the synology app, and run the first backup by clicking the provided button, the destination folder is created with the logged in user as owner (`admin` in my case), with very limited access rights (644), only the owner has write access. But the scheduled task will run as root user.

(Synology DSM 6.1.7-15284 Update 2, Hyperbackup 2.1.8)

Comment: Not sure about the chmod 777 (other solutions suggest changing the owner), but thanks for the helpful background.